# How to make Fn brightness keys work in an ASUS q/s301la?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have an ASUS q/s301la running 14.04 and as you may know (seems to not be just my computer), the brightness fn keys don't really work. I can change the brightness in settings or rc.local but the changes don't stick after a restart.

Comment: Please post your question and answer as [Q&A style](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions). Thanks

Comment: Woops! Sorry! Newbie here haha. I hope this is better.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any idea of how to fix those so I thought of a way to workaround it using crontabs!

Here's what I came up with (it's my first script outside of my Linux class... be nice.):

```
time=(date +%H)
if [$time -ge 2 -a $time -le 11]
then
  echo X > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
elif [$time -ge 11 -a $time -le 17]
  echo X > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
else 
  echo X > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
fi
```

Insert your desired brightness percentage (e.g. 60 or whatever) instead of X.

So you add this into crontabs (or the system scheduler) by using the bash command `crontabs -e` in terminal. You format it by adding a new line with: `* 0-23 * * * /path/script`. The asterisks tell the scheduler how often to run the script and I chose once every hour or *0-23*.

Basically what I hope this script does is: figure out what hour it is, save it in a variable $time, then compare it to my if, elseif, else statement, and then change the brightness accordingly in relation to the current hour!

You can also add this same script to `/etc/rc.local` so it runs at start up!

Hopefully this will help people with battery life, brightness control, resetting brightness at every startup, etc etc!

Comment: Welp... I fugured out this doesn't really work. Can anyone figure out why?

Comment: I changed up the code a bit to use >= and <= instead of -ge and -le and && instead of -a. In tests, it seems to work but in practice not so much...